# How do I identify multiple variables as one variable py

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x

Ok so I want to conserve space,and not write out all my variables,and a command. 
I want to do something like this

```
a = 1
b = 1
def add(var):
   var += 1
both = a and b
```

Can I do something like this or is it impossible. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do by `both = a and b `...

Comment: if you're simply wanting to set `both` to equal `1` then you can certainly do that ... but I suspect that is not your intent ...

Comment: Ok sorry this is a bad example for example  a=1,b =2, so how can i call them with both the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to add a variable to both a and b
you can do that with a container object but not a immutable variable.  When you want to change immutable variables like numbers or strings under the covers Python destroys the variable and creates another one in its place.

Here is a container example:

```
a = [1]
b = a
id(a) #gives the location of a in memory - 4352812552
id(b) # gives the same location - 4352812552
#both are the same

a[0] += 1
print(b)
```

Also a warning:  If you create a function to do this you will need to keep the variable names the same as the variables you want to change.

so:

```
def add(a, position):
    a[position] += 1
```

See this for more detailed explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns